# How to use respective colorbar when using facet_col with plotly.express?

Tags: python, plotly, imshow

I have a data which has three variables whose magnitudes are different.

I'm trying to apply `animation_frame` and `facet_col` to make them animate at the same time.

Here's the code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import xarray as xr

# Load xarray from dataset included in the xarray tutorial
ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('eraint_uvz').sel(level=500)

# convert Dataset to DataArray for animation
data = ds.to_array().transpose('month', ...)

# fix the bug
#   TypeError: %d format: a real number is required, not str
plot_data = data.assign_coords({'variable': range(len(data['variable']))})
fig = px.imshow(plot_data, animation_frame='month', facet_col='variable', color_continuous_scale='viridis')

# set variable back to string
#   https://community.plotly.com/t/cant-set-strings-as-facet-col-in-px-imshow/60904
for k in range(len(data['variable'])):
    fig.layout.annotations[k].update(text = data['variable'].values[k])
    
fig.show()
```

By default, they share the same colorbar like below.
Is it possible to make three colorbars (even different cmaps) with manual zmin/zmax values?

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71095107) and modified it.

It looks nice to me. Only the titles are in the wrong order.

```
fig = px.imshow(plot_data, animation_frame='month',
                facet_col='variable', facet_col_wrap=1,
                color_continuous_scale='viridis')

# set variable back to string
#   https://community.plotly.com/t/cant-set-strings-as-facet-col-in-px-imshow/60904
for k in range(len(data['variable'])):
    fig.layout.annotations[k].update(text = data['variable'].values[k])


# update traces to use different coloraxis
for i, t in enumerate(fig.data):
    t.update(coloraxis=f"coloraxis{i+1}")
for fr in fig.frames:
    # update each of the traces in each of the animation frames
    for i, t in enumerate(fr.data):
        t.update(coloraxis=f"coloraxis{i+1}")

# position / config all coloraxis
fig.update_layout(
    coloraxis={"colorbar": {"x": 1, "len": 0.3, "y": 0.85}},
    coloraxis2={
        "colorbar": {
            "x": 1,
            "len": 0.3,
            "y": 0.5,
        },
        "colorscale": 'Thermal',
    },
    coloraxis3={
        "colorbar": {"x": 1, "len": 0.3, "y": 0.15},
        "colorscale": 'Blues',
    },
)

fig.show()
```

[image: img]

Comment: I posted the [wrong title](https://community.plotly.com/t/wrong-title-when-changing-facet-col-wrap-value/71645?u=zxdawn) problem to plotly forum.